# I'm getting "Value is not a valid option" for SelectManyCheckBox 

Tags: java, jsf

I have this code in my JSP page:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="chb" value="#{MyBean.selectedCheckBoxes}" layout="pageDirection">
     <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.checkBoxItems}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

And in my MyBean:

```
public class MyBean {

    public MyBean() {
        for (Elem section : sections) {
            checkBoxItems.put(section.getName(), section.getObjectID());
        }
    }

    private String[] selectedCheckBoxes;
    private Map<String, Object> checkBoxItems = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

    public String save() {
        //save is not being executed....
        return FORWARD;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getCheckBoxItems() {
        return checkBoxItems;
    }

    public void setCheckBoxItems(Map<String, Object> checkBoxItems) {
        this.checkBoxItems = checkBoxItems;
    }

    public String[] getSelectedCheckBoxes() {
        return selectedCheckBoxes;
    }

    public void setSelectedCheckBoxes(String[] selectedCheckBoxes) {
        this.selectedCheckBoxes = selectedCheckBoxes;
    }
}
```

When I click save it is giving the below message in `<t:message for="chb"/>`

> "chb": Value is not a valid option.

**Even though I did not add the `required` attribute for `h:selectManyCheckbox`**, it is trying to validate or doing something else... 
I've changed `checkBoxItems`  variable type(with getter/setters) to `List<SelectItem>`, but it is not working as well.
What can be the reason, how can I solve it?
PS: I'm using JSF 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get this error when the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) test on a selected item has *not* returned `true` for *any* of the available items. So, when roughly the following happens under JSF's covers:

```
boolean valid = false;

for (Object availableItem : availableItems) {
    if (selectedItem.equals(availableItem)) {
        valid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!valid) {
    // Validation error: Value is not valid!
}
```

That can in your particular case only mean that `section.getObjectID()` does not return a `String` which is what your `selectedCheckboxes` is declared to, but a different type or a custom type where `equals()` is not implemented or broken.

---

**Update** as per your comment, the `getObjectID()` returns `Integer`. It's thus been treated as `String` because `selectedCheckBoxes` is declared as `String[]`. You should change the following

```
private String[] selectedCheckBoxes;
private Map<String, Object> checkBoxItems = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
```

to

```
private Integer[] selectedCheckBoxes;
private Map<String, Integer> checkBoxItems = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

and maybe (not sure, can't tell from top of head now) also explicitly supply a converter:

```html
<h:selectManyCheckbox ... converter="javax.faces.Integer">
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bauke.In my case `section.getObjectID()` returns `Integer`. Should I work with custom types where I can implement `equals()`.... I've changed my code to here is Java side:http://pastebin.com/jxnFGDQZ and this one is my JSP file http://pastebin.com/7T2yzP55 . However still the same message...

Comment: No, `Integer` is fine. You should only supply a converter. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt find any problem in th code, i thought there is the problem the list u passed to oneManyCheckBox.

hardcode some values in list in getter than check

```
  public Map<String, Object> getCheckBoxItems() {

    checkBoxItems.clear();
    checkBoxItems.put("aaaa", "aaaa");
    checkBoxItems.put("bbbb", "bbbb");
    checkBoxItems.put("cccc", "cccc");
    checkBoxItems.put("dddd", "dddd");
    checkBoxItems.put("eeee", "eeee");

    return checkBoxItems;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! All checkboxes are being rendered in the UI and the values are being passed to `checkBoxItems` properly....